# Split the distance in half?

Tags: word-usage, expressions

My friend and I live in two different cities. What I want to say is that when we meet we try to meet at a spot that is situated between the two cities , splitting the distance in half. What is the expression?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"Midpoint" or "Halfway" are the terms.

> [**midpoint**](https://www.google.com.hk/?hl=en&gws_rd=ssl#hl=en&q=midpoint+definition)
>
> noun
>
> 1. the exact middle point.
>      "the midpoint of each face of a cube"
> 2. a point somewhere in the middle.
>      "he would have been at the midpoint in his career"
>
> [**halfway**](https://www.google.com.hk/?hl=en&gws_rd=ssl#hl=en&q=Halfway+definition)
>
> adverb & adjective
>
> **at or to a point equidistant between two others.** "he stopped halfway down the passage"
>
> synonyms:  **midway, middle, mid**, central, centre, intermediate, **equidistant between two points**

Since you and your friend are meeting up, using 'halfway' is idiomatic. (context-based, because 'to meet halfway' could also mean, 'to compromise')

You may say, "Let's meet halfway." or "Let's meet halfway between (your city) and (your friend's city)."

Note: Midpoint is commonly used in Mathematics.

Comment: +1 for 'halfway'. I've been using it since years. Worth noting that the distances are 'approximately'!